# Rest Template binding with root array

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, resttemplate

I'm trying to use Rest Template to bind JSON to POJOs.

Imagine having a `SpaceX` class and a `Rocket` class, while the `SpaceX` class has a `List<Rocket>` attribute. I use the `@JsonProperty`  annotation to let the Rest Template bind "Rocket ID" and "name" inside a `Rocket` object automatically.

My JSON file starts as array like following:

```
[
  {
    "Rocket ID": "1",
     "name": "A"
  },
  {
    "Rocket ID": "2",
     "name": "B"
  }
]
```

I'm able to consume the JSON file and fill a `List<Rocket>` manually like this:

```
public <T> List<T> createObjectsFromJSON(Class<T[]> responseType) {
    ResponseEntity<T[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, request, responseType);
    T[] objects = responseEntity.getBody();
    List<T> list = Arrays.asList(objects);
    return list;
}
```

but I want to create a `SpaceX`object and let the Rest Template fill in the `List<Rocket>` automatically.
I can't wrap my head around the answer on how to do it. I can't tell the Rest Template to bind the list via `@JsonProperty`, because there is no name.

Comment: do you mean without changing the json structure, you want to accept SpaceX object instead of List<Rocket> ?

Comment: @pvpkiran Yes, the JSON structure can't be edited, because I'm using an API to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change JSON structure than you have to write custom serialization and deserialization logic. You can use @JsonCreator and @JsonValue annotations:

> The @JsonCreator annotation is used to tune the constructor/factory
>   used in deserialization. It’s very helpful when we need to deserialize
>   some JSON that doesn’t exactly match the target entity we need to get.
>
> @JsonValue indicates a single method that should be used to serialize
>   the entire instance.

Or @JsonSerialize and @JsonDeserialize:

> @JsonSerialize is used to indicate a custom serializer will be used to
>   marshall the entity.
>
> @JsonDeserialize is used to indicate the use of a custom deserializer.

This article contains more details and examples: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations